# Restart Webpack every file change

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I want my Webpack to reset everytime I change a file.

Currently I have a code like this:

```
watchOptions: {
  aggregateTimeout: 600,
  poll: true
},
```

(based on https://webpack.github.io/docs/cli.html#watchoptions-poll)

Which works, but not in the way I would like.

Expected:

- file is changed
- webpack restarts
- another file is changed
- webpack immediately restarts again

Actual situation:

- file is changed
- webpack restarts
- another file is changed
- webpack first needs to compile everything, and when he's done he will restart again

Any solutions / hints?

Or maybe it can't be done in Webpack?

Comment: `watch: true` have you used it?

Comment: @The yes, I have this too

Comment: I am beginning to wish that webpack worked like your 'expected' section. What is the point in completing the current compile if a file has already change? Makes things much, much slower.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you coudn't understand how *webpack* works. It takes file from *entry* point.

***webpack.config.js***

```
{
  entry: "./app.js",
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    filename: "bundle.js"
  }
}
```

if *entry file* has dependencies, it recursively take all of them and compile to a single file like *bundle.js* for example. So if you make a small changes into your file (doesnt matter which one), webpack should recompile all changes and give you ***new bundle.js*** file. If you look at this [`link`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/cli.html#watch-mode-watch) you will see

> Watch mode --
>
> watch Watches all dependencies and recompile on change.

So your *webpack* works correct, it is impossible to get correct *bundle.js* file without compilation all your files

I hope it will help you.

Thanks

Comment: So Webpack compares "old" bundle.js with "new" bundle.js? Makes sense.

Would be nice if one could tell Webpack to STOP compiling if a file changes during compilation, compile again and then compare it with the "old" file. 

And that's what I'm asking here for. I don't think that it would be impossible. "Server", or whatever it is should just do two thing at the same time - compile new bundle and listen for new changes. If we have new change - stop compiling and do it again.

Comment: You said, that "it is impossible to get correct bundle.js file without compilation all your files". Ok, but I don't want to get bundle.js after, lets say, first file save, but after, lets say, thrird file save. After save_1 and save_2 I only want Webpack to START compiling, but only after save_3 I want it to actually finish compiling and giving me the new bundle.js file.

Comment: @pbialy i think it doesnt compare `new` with `old`. It tracks whether you did changes or didnt.

Comment: @pbialy there is no way to track how many files have changed. of course you can increase `aggregateTimeout // Delay the rebuilt after the first change`, it triggers compilation every time when you change file, or event you can run webpack manually, without `watch` option.